# Text affecting div alignment

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm trying to get the tops of elements '.wrap1' and '.wrap2' to line up. As is you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benPearce/dDZ37/1/) that the top of 'wrap1' is a little below '.wrap2' yet when I delete the displayed text from '.wrap2' the tops do line up. Can any one explain why the text is lowering the top of '.wrap1'?

```
<html>

<body>
    <ul
    style="margin:0px 0px!important;position:relative;width:100%"
    class="mainList"
    id="dateMainList">
        <li
        class="list-element"
        id=""
        style="width:100%">
            <div
            class="list-inner-wrap"
            style="border:1px solid black">
                <div
                class="wrap1"
                style="display:inline-block;background:white;border:2px solid black;height:50px;width:50px">
                    <div
                    class="line-1"
                    style="display:block;text-align:center;font-size:10pt">1</div>
                        <div
                        class="line-2"
                        style="display:block;text-align:center;font-size:10pt">2</div>
                            <div
                            class="line-3"
                            style="display:block;text-align:center;font-size:10pt">3</div>
                                </div>
                                <div
                                class="wrap2"
                                style="display:inline-block;height:50px;background:green;width:200px"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    </li>
                                    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since they are both `display:inline-block` they are treated inline so you can put `vertical-align:top;` on both of them to line them up. Or you could make them `display:block` and `float:left`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` to `.wrap1 & wrap2` or just to`.wrap1`

Answer (score 0):

Do position:absolute; Any element that have that attribute will not affect any other element.